# JAVA asynchronous RMI

Tags: java, asynchronous, rmi

I need to have Remote Method invocation (RMI) functionality between two different JAVA programs. Both are supposed to perform some backend functionality on given file(File Name as parameter)sequentially. As the number of files to be processed can be too large, I require that the Remote Call to be done asynchronously. Initially I used Java RMI for this as it fits perfectly except that call is done synchronously. These are simple java programs and I don’t want to deploy them on any Application server as that would be too much overhead. Also multiple files need to be executed simultaneously so program is developed in thread-safe mode. Please suggest ideal implementation for that. Any custom developed API if available free would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have your RMI call start an asynchronous task.  If you want to improve efficiency you could send batches of files to process.  Note: unless you are careful, you disk subsystem could be your bottleneck and using multiple threads can be slower instead of faster.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to have Remote Method invocation (RMI) functionality between two different JAVA programs ... I require that the Remote Call to be done asynchronously.

Those two requirements are mutually contradictory. RMI means Remote Method Invocation, which implies call-and-return method call semantics. If it isn't call-and-return, it isn't method invocation, so it isn't RMI either.

You should investigate technologies that have listeners, such as JMS.

Comment: This isn't actually true. Asynchronous method calls typically use callbacks or some other form of continuation to process their return values. They are not normally fire-and-forget like an asynchronous message send, and nor are they like message sends in an actor system, whereby you need to explicitly listen for responses.

Comment: @BarryKelly Of course, but the question is about Java RMI, which does not have such a feature.

Answer (score 2):

The way to have true asynchronous call is to:

1. Implement RMI with NIO.
2. When the proxy is invoked put the request on the NIO selector and return immediately a result future to the caller.
3. Each request has to have a unique request id and when a response with that id arrive from the server the right future should be resolved.

There is only one implementation that I know of such [async RMI](https://github.com/barakb/asyncrmi)

Here is a good [explanation](http://barakb.github.io/asyncrmi/asynchronous-calls.html) with sequence diagram about how it is actually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You should JMS (Java Messaging Service) if you are sure both your applications are in Java (and are going to be). The communication being asynchronously there is also going to be a 3rd party broker - a message queue (ActiveMQ or one directly embedded in an application server like Glassfish or others).

By using this, you send the MQ and it sends the messages to the other application.

If you want more flexibility and maybe some of the applications are (or are going to be) written in another language you should probably use AMQP instead of JMS.

Answer (score 0):

Just spin up a thread and call the method from with the thread. Now you have async RMI ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another new player in RMI area which supports asynchronous execution. The [Redisson](https://redisson.org/) framework. More documentation about asynchronous execution is [here](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/wiki/9.-distributed-services#913-remote-service-asynchronous-calls).

Answer (score 0):

I'm with the same issue. Looking for reponses, I've found

- With the base libraries, it's not possible
- You can do polling (make calls every n time to know if something has changed) to emulate async.
- Use JMS or other messaging system
- Found this github project, but not checked myself: https://github.com/barakb/asyncrmi
- Use a RMI server in every client
- Use gRPC / Java, which by design accepts futures and streams. It involves use IDL and generate more complex code, but it works neat.

I have choosen the last option